# JCR explorer for RepositoryImpl

Tags: jackrabbit, jcr

I've created a JackRabbit content repository instance with the following lines:

```
   File repositoryConfig = new File(getClass().getResource("/repository.xml").toURI());
   RepositoryConfig conf = RepositoryConfig.install(repositoryConfig, new File("MY_JCR_HOME_ADDRESS"));
   RepositoryImpl repository = RepositoryImpl.create(conf);
```

Now I want to run a JCR explorer on it. I've tried different JCR explorers like JackrabbitExplorer and JCR-Explorer. But all of them works with JNDI or web-based repositories.

**My question is that how can I run a JCR explorer on a RepositoryImpl instance.**

Comment: Where is your server? Are you running a standalone Jackrabbit instance?

Comment: @tmarwen Sorry for posting late. I don't have a standalone Jackrabbit instance. My Jackrabbit instance is created via org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl class

Comment: And where are you hosting that repository?

Comment: Like yourself, I couldn't find an explorer so I made a simple one with swing and JTree! Took less than a day.

Comment: Post your comment as answer plz to I accept it. @TedTrippin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested :)

Like yourself, I couldn't find an explorer so I made a simple one with swing and JTree! Took less than a day.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Toromiro](http://www.subshell.com/en/toromiro/) which is a JCR browser and editor for local and remote repositories. The documentation describes how to connect to a JackRabbit repository by RMI, WebDAV or just by specifying a local repository.xml.